# Route problems on symfony 2.6

Tags: php, symfony

I'm a beginner with symfony and I got my first route problem.

My controller is :

```
/**
* Dossier controller.
*
* @Route("/dossier")
*/
class DossierController extends Controller
```

Inside my class, I want to create a new route for an admin on this route :

- @Route("/gestionnaire/etatcivil", name="etat_civil")
- @Method("GET")

But I got a 404 not found on this adress.
All the other URL are correct and work fine, it's the only route I have a problem with!

Is there someone who has any clue ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can debug your routes with the command `app/console router:debug` for list every routes and then check one route like this: `app/console router:debug etat_civil`
You can also try your routes with `app/console router:match /dossier` for exemple.

Comment: Thanks for the command. I got the solution. I didn't know the name in the route cannot be set another time to the same name and I was already using etat_civil.

Comment: Note: `debug:router` is the proper command with `router:debug` being an alias (for BC reasons, I assume). I often get weird results (only showing a few of the routes) when I use `router:debug` for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple. (I answer to myself)

The name cannot be the same of another name. I just change "etat_civil" by something else and it was good.